# How do we check if an object value is compatible with a primitive type field in Java

Tags: java, reflection

I want to develop a `bindTo` utility method that initializes all the fields of an object (i.e. the `target`) with all compatible values contained in a `Map<String, Object>` (where the key is the name of the field).
Consider that `f` represents a field in the `target` object and `vals` is the `Map` containing the initialization values, so I must:

1. check if the map `vals` contains an entry with a key equals to the field name.
2. if that entry exists, then I have to check if its value is compatible with the field’s type.
3. and if it is, then I must set that value to the field `f` in the `target` object.

This corresponds to the following code:

```java
/*
 * 1. checks if the map `vals` contains an entry with a key equals to the field name:
 */
String fName = f.getName();
if(vals.containsKey(fName)){
   /*
    * 2. if that entry exists, then checks if its value is compatible with the field’s type:
    */
   Class<?> fType = f.getType();
   Object fValue = vals.get(fName);
   if(fType.isAssignableFrom(fValue.getClass())){
       /*
        * 3. and if it is, then set that value to the field `f` in the `target` object:
        */
       f.setAccessible(true);
       f.set(target, fValue);
   }
}
```

Yet, this approach does not work when we have primitive type fields, because a wrapper type is not compatible with the corresponding primitive type. For instance, an `Integer` type is not compatible with an `int` and will not satisfy the condition: `fType.isAssignableFrom(fValue.getClass())`

So, do you have any suggestion to suppress this limitation with primitive type fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the target field is a primitive type, then you can get its default value via reflection, which in turn will be boxed in a wrapper object. From this object you may get the corresponding wrapper type. So, you can replace the following line of your code:

```java
Class<?> fType = f.getType();
```

with:

```java
Class<?> fType = f.getType();
if(fType.isPrimitive()){
  fType = f.get(target).getClass();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an auxiliary service to get the corresponding wrapper type of a primitive, such as the `toWrapper` method of the `WrapperUtilites` class provided bellow. So instead of writing:

```java
Class<?> fType = f.getType();
```

You may write:

```java
Class<?> fType = WrapperUtilites.toWrapper(f.getType());
```

The `WrapperUtilites` can be written such as:

```
class WrapperUtilites{

      final static Map<Class<?>, Class<?>> wrappers = new HashMap<>();

      static{
          wrappers.put(boolean.class, Boolean.class);
          wrappers.put(short.class, Short.class);
          wrappers.put(int.class, Integer.class);
          …
          // do this for all primitive types
      }

      public static Class<?> toWrapper(Class<?> c){
          return c.isPrimitive()? wrappers.get(c) : c;
      }
}
```